# Construct a differential equation that models how long the object takes to fall and its velocity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An object falls from a building. Assuming the object has a mass of 80kg and it falls into is 4000m deep water. Assume that the force due to air resistance is proportional to the velocity of the object with proportionality constant 15 N-sec/m. Write up a differential equation that models its fall and find out how long the object falls, and its velocity when hits the water. (Assume acceleration due to gravity is 9.5 m/sec2).

Here's what i think it should be:

80 y'' + 15y = 0, y(0) = 4000, y'(0)=0

I'm not sure where i should be using the acceleration due to gravity. Overall, i'm not sure if i'm doing this right

Answer (score 0):

You should have $$80g-15\dot{y}=80\ddot{y}$$

Since resistance is proportional to velocity, and the weight is obviously relevant. Use $g=9.8$ perhaps?